# How do I add a heading to a cluetip tooltip, when I am sourcing content from a hidden div (versus title attribute)

Tags: jquery, tooltip, cluetip, html-heading

I  [am using cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/) which works great but the content of one of my tooltips  is getting very big so I want to move it from sitting inside the local title attribute into a seperate and hidden div.

This works fine except for the fact that I can't figure out how to add a title to the Tooltip.  When I had the title attribute content here was my tooltip code:

```
$('#subscribe').cluetip({
    cluetipClass: 'jtip',
    activation: 'click',
    topOffset: 10,
    leftOffset: -175,
    splitTitle: '|',
    sticky: true,
    closePosition: 'title',
    arrows: true
});
```

and here is my new code with the hidden div:

```
$('#subscribe').cluetip({
    local:true,
    cluetipClass: 'jtip',
    activation: 'click',
    topOffset: 10,
    leftOffset: -175,
    sticky: true,
    closePosition: 'title',
    arrows: true
});
```

As you can see **splitTitle: '|'** goes away and **local:true** gets added (as it seem like the tooltip is empty if I include "splitTitle" when using local: true.

Given that I can't use splitTitle, how can I have a title at the top of my cluetip tooltip when I am sourcing the tooltip from a hidden div.  In the demo example on the website, it seems like none of the examples using hidden divs show a heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a tooltip title attribute by setting a "title" attribute on the tooltip triggering element. So your HTML will look like

```
<!-- your trigger -->    
<a class="load-local" href="#loadme" rel="#loadme" title="Put your tooltip title here">
    I trigger tooltip
</a>
<!-- your local tooltip -->
<div id="loadme">
    this is hidden local content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like Michal said, here's the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/6jfDc/

Answer (score 0):

You can't using the plugin as it is.

The plugin generates the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="cluetip">
    <div class="cluetip-outer">
        <h3 class="cluetip-title />
        <div class="cluetip-inner" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Looking at the source code of the plugin ([GitHub](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-cluetip/blob/master/jquery.cluetip.js)):

```
/***************************************
* load an element from the same page
***************************************/
      } else if (opts.local) {
        var $localContent = $(tipAttribute + (/^#\S+$/.test(tipAttribute) ? '' : ':eq(' + index + ')')).clone(true).show();
        if (opts.localIdSuffix) {
          $localContent.attr('id', $localContent[0].id + opts.localIdSuffix);
        }
        $cluetipInner.html($localContent);
        cluetipShow(pY);
      }
    };
```

The "local content" (from you div in your situation) is appended to `$cluetipInner` which is the element `div.cluetip-inner`. The `<h3>` element gets completely ignored.

---

Note: about the splitTitle options, documentation says:

> splitTitle: if used, the clueTip will be populated **only** by the title attribute

Comment: thanks for your research . . .I understand and read that splitTitle only works by using the title attribute. It just seems like an obvious gap that you can't easily set a title using local content or ajax response . . . why would the functionality be different just because the data source of the content is different?

Comment: The same behavior happens with ajax-loaded tooltip. I don't know if it can be considered as just another data source, the data structure is also different (title = pure text, ajax/local = markup (expected at least)). I think your best shot would be to hide the header if it is empty for instance (with `onActivate` or `onShow` callbacks)

Comment: thanks for the reply . . conceptually (IMO) it does seem like just another source of data (regardless how the API is built).  IMO the functionality and "data sourcing" would be decoupled  and unrelated